# ansible, command module and jq with pipe

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to run a docker command that returns a list of containers, and their size.

The command is `docker container ls  --format  "{\"name\":\"{{.Names}}\", \"size\":\"{{.Size}}\"}  " --all | jq --slurp`

When I try to run this in an Ansible playbook it explodes:

```
- name: Get cointainer size
      raw: /path/to/script/docker-cointainer-size.sh
```

The truncated error is:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 2
  stderr: |-
    jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe]
    Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]
...
```

I suspect this has something to do with the use of the pipe (|), as when I remove this, and the subsequent `jq` command, the playbook completes successfully.

The `.sh` script does work correctly when run manually.

I have also tried using the `shell` module, as well as the `command` module - both are unable to run the script.

How can I use `jq` and the pipe function in an Ansible playbook?

Comment: have you checked that your script is returning proper return code when triggered manually?

Comment: Yes, it is working correctly when run manually.

Comment: i am not talking about working but about return code (`echo $?` when your script is done)

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce this problem. Your script and playbook seem to run just fine.  What version of `jq` are you using? Does the problem go away if you pass `jq` a filter on the command, as indicated in the usage message? I was surprised that it works without this when using `--slurp`.

Comment: AFAIK `jq` **mandates** a selector, even if it's just `.` to copy the input to the output

Comment: Have you considered going the ansible way ? use `command` to get your docker result without piping to jq and parse with `command_result.stdout | from_json`

Comment: Have you tried encasing the whole statement in quotes? Also the indentation before raw seems to be a bit too much

Comment: @Matthew L Daniel: "rc: 2" supports your explanation. Exit code 2: there was any usage problem or system error.

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel it doesn't _always_ mandate it [for some time already](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/476), but it can be confusing, as seen here.

Answer (score 1):

The exit code says:

> rc: 2
>     stderr: |-
>       jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe]
>       Usage: jq [options]  [file...]

jq [exit code 2](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/) means:

> there was any usage problem or system error

man jq shows:

> jq [options...] filter [files...]

"filter" is missing. Put a "." for example to copy the input

> jq --slurp .