# Issue in ansible playbook command?

Tags: shell, docker, ansible, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to execute a command on docker on other machine from my machine. When I execute this command:

```
- name: Add header
      command: docker exec cli bash -l -c "echo '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"gll", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":'$(cat jaguar_update.json)'}}}' | jq . > jaguar_update_in_envelope.json"
```

through ansible playbook, I am getting the error shown below.

```
fatal:[  
   command-task
]:FAILED! =>{  
   "changed":true,
   "cmd":[  ],
   "delta":"0:00:00.131115",
   "end":"2019-07-11 17:32:44.651504",
   "msg":"non-zero return code",
   "rc":4,
   "start":"2019-07-11 17:32:44.520389",
   "stderr":"mesg: ttyname   
failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device\nparse error: Invalid numeric   
literal at line 1, column 9",
   "stderr_lines":[  
      "mesg: ttyname failed: 
Inappropriate ioctl for device",
      "parse error: Invalid numeric literal 
at line 1, column 9"
   ],
   "stdout":"",
   "stdout_lines":[  

   ]
}
```

But if I manually execute command in the docker container, it works fine and I don't get any issue.

EDIT:
As suggested i tried with `shell` module

```
shell: docker exec cli -it bash -l -c "echo '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"gll", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":'$(cat jaguar_update.json)'}}}' | jq . > jaguar_update_in_envelope.json"
```

But i get below error as

> fatal: [command-task]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "docker
>   exec cli -it bash -l -c echo
>   '{\"payload\":{\"header\":{\"channel_header\":{\"channel_id\":\"gll\",
>   \"type\":2}},\"data\":{\"config_update\":'$(cat
>   jaguar_update.json)'}}}' | jq . > jaguar_update_in_envelope.json",
>   "delta": "0:00:00.110341", "end": "2019-07-12 10:21:45.204049", "msg":
>   "non-zero return code", "rc": 4, "start": "2019-07-12
>   10:21:45.093708", "stderr": "cat: jaguar_update.json: No such file or
>   directory\nparse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 4",
>   "stderr_lines": ["cat: jaguar_update.json: No such file or directory",
>   "parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 4"], "stdout":
>   "", "stdout_lines": []}

All the files 'jaguar_update.json' present in the working directory. I have confirmed the working directory.

**Above commands works if i put it in a shell script file then execute the shell script from ansible.**

Comment: Can you try `docker exec -it  cli bash -l -c ` The `-it` option for interactive terminal. Try it.

Comment: it did not work

Comment: Can you try shell module?

Comment: `shell` is needed here instead of `command`. Pipes and redirection do not work with `command`. The next problem will be the nested quotation.

Comment: How should i use the shell here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid any complexity, try [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55584559/6309) to wrap your command in a script, and call that script (with `command` or `shell`)

```
- name: Add header
      raw: /path/to/script/docker-add-header.sh
```

And in `/path/to/script/docker-add-header.sh`:

```
docker exec cli -it bash -l -c "echo '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"gll", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":'$(cat jaguar_update.json)'}}}' | jq . > jaguar_update_in_envelope.json
```

Try to make the script work first alone (no Ansible).
See (if it is not working, even outside any Ansible call), to escape nested double-quotes:

```
docker exec cli -it bash -l -c "echo '{\"payload\":{\"header\":...
```

Comment: haha. That's what i have done for now as a fix to it. But i was seeking solution for ansible also :-)

Comment: @DhirajKumar I understand. But after many trials, that is what I ended up doing as well: using a script.

Comment: Thanks @Vonc. I think then we only left with shell script solution

Comment: @DhirajKumar I agree: let us wait the end of your bounty and see if anyone has a better solution to offer.

Answer (score 3):

As everyone has mentioned this does need you to use `shell` instead of `command`. Now you want to simplify this command so it can run first in bash. Which can be done easily using `printf`

```sh
$ printf "%s%s%s" '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"gll", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":' $(<jaguar_update.json'}}}' | jq . > jaguar_update_in_envelope.json

$ cat jaguar_update_in_envelope.json
{
  "payload": {
    "header": {
      "channel_header": {
        "channel_id": "gll",
        "type": 2
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "config_update": {
        "name": "tarun"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So now our commands runs without issues. Next is to move it with `bash -l -c` format. So instead using `-c` which requires us to pass the whole command as one parameter, we use the multiline commands

```
$ bash -l <<EOF
printf "%s%s%s" '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"gll", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":' $(<jaguar_update.json) '}}}' | jq . > jaguar_update_in_envelope.json
EOF
```

But this fails with an error

```
{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"gll", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":{bash: line 2: name:: command not found
bash: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
bash: line 3: `} '}}}' | jq . > jaguar_update_in_envelope.json'
```

This is because the `EOF` format will treat each new line as a different command. So we need to replace all new line characters

```sh
bash -l <<EOF
printf "%s%s%s" '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"gll", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":' $(sed -E 's|"|\\"|g' jaguar_update.json | tr -d '\n') '}}}' | jq . > jaguar_update_in_envelope.json
EOF
```

And now in ansible

```
- name: a play that runs entirely on the ansible host
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
     - name: Solve the problem
       shell: |
           bash -l <<EOF
                printf "%s%s%s" '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"gll", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":' $(sed -E 's|"|\\"|g' jaguar_update.json | tr -d '\n') '}}}' | jq . > jaguar_update_in_envelope.json
           EOF
```

And the result

```sh
$ ansible-playbook test.yml
PLAY [a play that runs entirely on the ansible host] *********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [Solve the problem] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1]

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$ cat jaguar_update_in_envelope.json
{
  "payload": {
    "header": {
      "channel_header": {
        "channel_id": "gll",
        "type": 2
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "config_update": {
        "name": "tarun"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

c.f. the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html) -

- The command(s) will not be processed through the shell, so variables like $HOME and operations like "<", ">", "|", ";" and "&" will not work. Use the shell module if you need these features.

[shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) pretty literally submits a script to the sh command parser.

Another note - you end the single-quote before the `$(cat jaguar_update.json)` and restart it after, but don't use any double quoting around it. Your output may handle that, but I wanted to call attention in case it matters.